# How to find out what executables came from a particular gem?

Tags: bash, terminal, rubygems

I am using `gem` through the terminal CLI.
I know `$ gem list` lists the installed gems.
But how do I find the names of the actual executables associated with a particular gem?

For example, CocoaPods.

The gem is called `cocoapods`. (I installed it using `$ sudo gem install cocoapods`).
But the actual executable is called `pod`.

At the moment the best thing I found was `$ gem contents <gemName>` and then looking through the list, specifically any files inside `.../bin/` that don't have an extension. But this method does not seem ideal...

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found what I needed:

To list all the executables for a particular gem:

```
$ gem specification <gemName> executables
```

(this basically reads the `gemspec` file)

---

If you want to list all the executables for all the installed gems, here is the above command in a loop:

```
gem list --no-versions | while read -r gemName ; do
    echo "Executables for $gemName:"
    gem specification $gemName executables
done
```

*(Note 1: I copy-pasted this directly in my terminal and hit `enter`)

(Note 2: This ran for a while, in my case ~30 seconds for ~100 gems)*